# Getting error while using NSBundle?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, debugging

I used path to documents to link external file in app. But when I want to run the project on real iPhone, I replaced the path with NSBundle. Now I'm getting error because of NSBundle(I think) or something else. How can I debug it?

error in console: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

the whole code:

```
import UIKit

func assign() -> [String]{

    let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
    let path = bundle.pathForResource("words", ofType: "txt")
    let content = String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)//xcode marked that line with green
    let newArray = content!.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
    return newArray

}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {



    let newArray: [String] = assign()
    @IBOutlet weak var textBox: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var firstInput: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        firstInput.returnKeyType = .Search
        firstInput.delegate = self
        textBox.text = ""
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func getFromPath() {
        //getFromPath() func used to be in assign func.
        var letters = firstInput.text
        var res = search(set: newArray, letters: letters)
        textBox.text! = ""
        for element in res {
            textBox.text = (textBox.text ?? "") + "\n" + "\(element)"
        }

    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
       if firstInput.text == "" {
       }
       else {
        getFromPath()
       }
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        return false
    }


    func search(#set: [String], letters: String) -> [String] {
        let result = filter(set) { item in
            for char in letters {
                if !contains(item, char) {
                    return false
                }
            }
            return true
        }
        return result
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag your file to your project and place it together with your projects files. Make sure you select copy items if needed:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let wordsUrl = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("words", withExtension: "txt")!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var error: NSError?

        if wordsUrl.checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError(&error) {
            println(true)
            if let myString = String(contentsOfURL: wordsUrl, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error) {
                let myArray = myString.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
                println(myArray)
            } else if let error = error {
                println(error.description)
            }
        } else if let error = error {
            println(error.description)
        }
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you dont have that file in your bundle.

Make sure the file has been added to the target, check in the inspector.

Wrap critical initialization in

```
if let someObject = source as? someType
{

}
```

Comment: Where I need to place the file? I placed it in the upper directory of ViewController.Swift

Comment: That is fine. Select the file and look in the inspector to the right to see if your app target is selected. This will make the file available to the target build. You should also set breakpoints on the line of path, and contents, and po (print object) in the debugger. e.g. po path and see if its valid, if not it cant find the file. Maybe a typo?